# What is the difference between flux cache(), replay() and publish() if creating a hot publisher?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

What is the difference between flux `cache()`, `replay()` and `publish()` if creating a hot publisher? For which use case which operator would suit best?

The following samples replays all 5 elements for the 3 different methods.

`cache()`:

```
        var flux = Flux.fromStream(Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5))
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).cache();

        flux.doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("First: " + v))
        .subscribe();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        flux.doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("Second: " + v))
                .subscribe();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
```

`replay()`:

```
        var flux = Flux.fromStream(Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5))
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).replay();

        flux.doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("First: " + v))
        .subscribe();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        flux.doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("Second: " + v))
                .subscribe();

        flux.connect();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
```

`publish()`:

```
        var flux = Flux.fromStream(Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5))
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).publish();

        flux.doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("First: " + v))
        .subscribe();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        flux.doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("Second: " + v))
                .subscribe();

        flux.connect();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
```

One variation of printed result:

```
First: 1
First: 2
First: 3
First: 4
Second: 1
Second: 2
Second: 3
Second: 4
First: 5
Second: 5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cache()` is a convenience alias to `.replay().autoConnect(1)`, ie. it will perform the `connect()` for you as soon as the first subscriber comes in.

but since it replays the whole history, the second subscriber still sees all elements.

from your `replay()` and `publish()` examples, you might think there is no difference between the two. but that is because you `connect()` AFTER both subscribers have subscribed...

if you were to move `connect()` call before the second subscriber, you would see that in the case of `publish()` it wouldn't see any value. `replay()` on the other hand would *replay* the whole history to the second subscriber, despite it being late.